# How to remove duplicates from QcomboBox in pyqt4 python

Tags: python, duplicates, pyqt4, qcombobox

How to remove duplicates from combobox in pyqt4 . i have tried following code but its not removing duplicates from comboBox.

Code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QWidget()
w.resize(500, 388)

combo=QtGui.QComboBox(w)
combo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 251, 31))
combo.addItem("aa")
combo.addItem("bb")
combo.addItem("cc")
combo.addItem("aa")
combo.setDuplicatesEnabled(False)

w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have not read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#duplicatesEnabled-prop):

> This property holds whether **the user can enter duplicate** items into
>   the combobox.
>
> Note that it **is always possible to programmatically** insert duplicate
>   items into the combobox.
>
> By default, this property is false (duplicates are not allowed).
>
> ---

<sub>the highlight is mine</sub>

So a possible solution is to overwrite the addItem method to do the filtering:

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class ComboBox(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def addItem(self, item):
        if item not in self.get_set_items():
            super(ComboBox, self).addItem(item)

    def addItems(self, items):
        items = list(self.get_set_items() | set(items))
        super(ComboBox, self).addItems(items)

    def get_set_items(self):
        return set([self.itemText(i) for i in range(self.count())])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(500, 388)

    combo = ComboBox(w)
    combo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 251, 31))
    combo.addItems(["aaa", "bb", "aaa"])
    combo.addItem("aa")
    combo.addItem("bb")
    combo.addItem("cc")
    combo.addItem("aa")
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#duplicatesEnabled-prop):

> Note that it is always possible to programmatically insert duplicate items into the combobox.

You need to manually avoid duplicates. You could make a `set` of all the items and then pass its items with `addItem`.